# How to deal with XML Attributes that have no values?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm currently writing a program where I am parsing many XML files.
One attribute I am interested in is shown below:
[XML Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkYNF.png)

I am wanting to extract the value of this tag. Occasionally, some XML files contain this tag, but have no value, this breaks my code:

```
citation = document.getElementsByTagName("r3d:citationGuidelineURL")

for cit in citation:
        print(cit.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

How do I check whether there is a node value and stop my program crashing with an Attribute error?

Comment: you can always use `try-catch` for this, although you'll have to assign it some value

Comment: @DevanshuMisra thanks, that has sorted my issue

Comment: Your example is an element, not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

ElementTree based solution

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
   <a>value1</a>
   <a></a> 
   <a>value2</a>     
</root>'''

doc = ET.fromstring(xml)
a_list = doc.findall("a")
for a in a_list:
    if a.text:
        print(a.text)
    else:
        print('Empty Element')
```

Output

```
value1
Empty Element
value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem recently, and I solved it by adding a continue
like this:

```py
citation = document.getElementsByTagName("r3d:citationGuidelineURL")

for cit in citation:
  if not cit.firstChild:
    continue
  print(cit.firstChild.nodeValue)
```